# Retrieving values in a string between two asterisks using SSIS 2008 R2

Tags: ssis

I have a field with 2 asterisks in the middle of other character data.  I need to retrieve the value between the asterisks.  For instance, I have 
`DOE*JOHN*L` and I need `JOHN`.

I've written the following:

```
SUBSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1) + 1, (FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",2) - FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1) - 2))
```

When I try to run it I get an `DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR` message and it fails.

If I remove the -2 at the end it works, but I have 2 extra characters.  So, using the above example, I'll have `JOHN*L`.

I've got this in derived column in the SSIS Package.  It's part of a process of importing a fixed length file into SQL Server.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Have you confirmed that *every* data item you are putting through this expression has `[Some Text]*[More Text]*[At Least 1 Character]`?

Comment: There is at least one, so my complete expression is:  LEN(EMPLOYE_NAME) - LEN(REPLACE(EMPLOYE_NAME,"*","")) == 1 ? SUBSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1) + 1,LEN(EMPLOYE_NAME)) : SUBSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1) + 1, (FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",2) - FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1) - 2))

Comment: Please see my answer for the correct expression to use in your `Derived Column` task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in SQL using `CHARINDEX` instead of `FINDSTRING`:

```
SUBSTRING(EMPLOYE_NAME, CHARINDEX('*',EMPLOYE_NAME) + 1, CHARINDEX('*',EMPLOYE_NAME,CHARINDEX('*',EMPLOYE_NAME)))
```

I tested with `'DOE*JOHN*L'` and `'DOE*JOHN'` and both return `JOHN`.

EDIT:

After creating a long-winded write up about adding conditional splits, I figured out the problem with you original `Derived Column` expression. I was able to use the following expression to handle names with 1 space, or 1 asterisk, or 2 asterisks. Make sure you don't have any line feeds or carriage returns in the expression string.

```
LEN(EMPLOYE_NAME) - LEN(REPLACE(EMPLOYE_NAME," ","")) == 1 ? (SUBSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME)," ",1) + 1,LEN(EMPLOYE_NAME)) ): (FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",2) > 0? (SUBSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1) + 1,(FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",2) - FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1)) - 1)): (SUBSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1) + 1,(LEN(EMPLOYE_NAME) - FINDSTRING(TRIM(EMPLOYE_NAME),"*",1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to do it all in SSIS, but I'll keep this in mind if it doesn't work out that way.

Comment: @user10380435 Please see my edited answer for the correct expression to use in a single `Derived Column` task. No need for Script tasks or Conditional Splits.

Comment: Thanks!  This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you always want the data between the 1st and 2nd asterisk then I would use a script component and Split()

```
    string[] strs = Row.str.ToString().Split('*');

    Row.BetweenStars = strs[1]; //Note Split is 0 based and 1 is the second value in the array
```

Make sure you add str (my name of your column) to the input as readonly.

Add BetweenStars as output with data type string length of 255.

**Edit:**

Looking at your data more closely, I think your data might actually be like this:

LastName[star]FirstName[star]Middle

In that case you can set all 3 using split.

```
LastName = strs[0];
FirstName = strs[1];
Middle = strs[2];
```

**Edit after comment regarding either 1 or 2 stars:**

```
    string[] strs = Row.str.ToString().Split('*');

    if (strs.Length == 2)
    {
        //This is where first name and last name only exist
        Row.LastName = strs[0];
        Row.FirstName = strs[1];
        Row.Middle_IsNull = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        //This is where all 3 exist
        Row.LastName = strs[0];
        Row.FirstName = strs[1];
        Row.Middle = strs[2];
    }
```

Comment: I have data like this:  LastName[star]FirstName[star]Middle and also LastName[star]FirstName.   I've added a condition statement in the expression and the 1 star path works as expected.  I'll look into the script option.  thanks.

Comment: @user10380435 Edited answer to handle both 1 and 2 stars